# MySQL error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

Tags: sql, mysql, node.js

I want to connect to my sql with node js and create tables if there are no tables, but I get the following error.

Mistake:
sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Trips (\n" +
' trip_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,\n' +
" ' at line 9"

My code:

```
const createTables = `
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Members (
    user_id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    member_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    date DATE,
    time TIME
  );
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Trips (
    trip_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    city_id INT NOT NULL,
    trip_description TEXT
  );
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Participants (
    trip_id INT,
    user_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (trip_id, user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (trip_id) REFERENCES Trips(trip_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES Members(user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
  );
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Cities (
    city_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    city_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
  );
`;


pool.query(createTables, (err, results) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log('Tables created successfully');
  }
});
```